# Can't create user

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine

I was using MongoDB version 2.6.6 on Google Compute Engine and used the click to deploy method.

```
rs0:SECONDARY> db.createUser({user:"admin", pwd:"secret_password", roles:[{role:"root", db:"admin"}]})
2015-07-13T15:02:28.434+0000 Error: couldn't add user: not master at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1004

rs0:SECONDARY> use admin
switched to db admin
rs0:SECONDARY> db.createUser({user:"admin", pwd:"secret_password", roles:["root"]})
2015-07-13T15:13:28.591+0000 Error: couldn't add user: not master at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1004
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB will be deployed in a cluster of Compute Engine instances (also known as a MongoDB replica set).  Each instance will use a boot disk and separate disk for database files.

Primary and master nodes are the nodes that can accept writes. MongoDB’s replication is “single-master:” only one node can accept write operations at a time.

Secondary and slave nodes are read-only nodes that replicate from the primary.

Your error message looks like you are trying to add the user on the secondary. Try adding the user in the primary.

Comment: I am using only one replica which is primary and getting the same result as Lolxdnub

Answer (score 30):

I had a similar problem with mongo 3.2:

> Error: couldn't add user: not master :

When trying to create a new user, with root role.

I was using only a local copy of mongo.

In my mongod.conf file I had the following uncommented:

```
replication:
   replSetName:  <node name>
```

Commenting that out and restarting fixed the problem. I guess mongo thought it was part of a replication set, and was confused as to who the Master was.

Edit:

I've also found that if you ARE trying to setup a replication set, and you get the above error, then run:

rs.initiate()

This will start a replication set, and set the current node as PRIMARY.

Exit, and then log back in and you should see:

PRIMARY>

Now create users as needed.

Comment: This might work, but it is directly contrary to the guide here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/ I'm thinking it's a bug. Also got this with v3.2.9.

Comment: @EddieKumar Can I ask what version of Mongo were you using?

Comment: @comfytoday I was using 4.01, someone cloned the host VM, hence I didn't realise that replication was enabled, disabling it helped.

Comment: 4 years later, still running into this issue.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this error when scripting replica set creation.

The solution was to add a delay between `rs.initiate()` and `db.createUser()`.

Replica set creation is seemingly done in background and it takes time for the primary node to actually become primary. In interactive use this doesn't cause a problem because there is a delay while typing the next command, but when scripting the interactions the delay may need to be forced.

Comment: It depends on the speed of the internet on the server and I added 30 seconds sleep command to my script.

Comment: Creating delay is not a clean way and may cause errors in production.
I think there should be a better way to do it, but if you don't find another way, use the retry mechanism instead of a simple delay.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I thought I was running mongo 3.4 but it was mongo 3.6. Uninstalling 3.6 and installing 3.4 fixed my issue.